# Compiling jabber-net in Xamarin Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xmpp, xamarin

I am trying to compile [jabber-net](https://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) in Xamarin Studio so I can use it in a Xamarin.iOS app.
From other searches I have done I am told I need to recompile the source.

From command line I can build the dll, but I have no idea what version of .NET/Mono this is targeting.
This makes a jabber-net.dll and a jabber-net.dll.mdb.
If I add jabber-net.dll to my project, add the reqiured

```
using jabber.client;
...
...
...
JabberClient client = new JabberClient ();
```

and try to compile I am told.

> /Users/brad/Projects/XMPPChat/XMPPChat/AppDelegate.cs(37,47): error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not import type `jabber.client.JabberClient' from`jabber-net, Version=2.1.0.702, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=924c5b18328d6f09'
>   /Users/brad/Projects/XMPPChat/XMPPChat/AppDelegate.cs(37,38): error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not import type `jabber.client.JabberClient' from`jabber-net, Version=2.1.0.702, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=924c5b18328d6f09'
>   /Users/brad/Projects/XMPPChat/XMPPChat/AppDelegate.cs(37,38): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

I got no idea what is going on here... 
When I try to open any of the .sln's (or include any of the existing projects, even the mono specific project) that came with jabber-net into my solution it will either hang trying to convert the project, or will tell me

> The file '/Users/brad/Projects/XMPPChat/JabberNet-2.1.0.710/mono-jabber-net.csproj' could not be loaded.

and will spit out [this](http://pastebin.com/4TLVDcEQ) error.

Any idea where to go from here? :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a new solution from scratch, and add all of the `.cs` files except those in the test and examples directories.  Also make sure you don't have an old version of the .dll around somewhere.

Comment: Just tried that, got quite a few errors. It does not know what `Org.System.Xml.Sax` is (txt2xml?).  `IContentHandler`, `IErrorHandler` are also unknown and apparently `FileSystemWatcher` does not exist in System.IO for Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Remove `SynchElementStream.cs`.  Comment out the FileWatcher stuff (anything that has `m_watcher` in it) in `ConfigFile.cs`.

Comment: Got it to compile by just commenting out whatever would error, I believe a lot of the things were forms related. If not, they were hardly used.
Unfortunately this came a day too late and we decided to implement our own chat system as we were unsure if jabber would meet our requirements within our timeframe.